# create instance of object inside jquery click function

Tags: javascript, instance

Hi I've just playing with some `oojs`, I've tried to complete a what is a very simple test.

check out the code here :
[view the test jsbin](http://jsbin.com/petegefoluve/2/edit?html,js,output)

I noticed I couldn't create a new instance of an object inside a function, without moving it outside the function or by pre-pending it with window eg

> window.person = new person();

I've a feeling this is wrong.

so my question is , is their a better way to do this,
and is using  `window.person` a bad idea to create a new instance.

Comment: `window.Person = new Person(clicked);` as you did is particularly bad, because you are overwriting the `Person` constructor with an instance created by it. You should use `person = new Person(…)` to distinguish the two.

Comment: ah! never noticed that, silly mistake this makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your new Person instance is overwriting the constructor.

When defining a function outside of a scope you're actually attaching it to the window object (the "global" scope). This means that your `function Person` is assigned to `window.Person`.

Inside your click event you re-assign `window.Person` with `window.Person = new Person(clicked);`

You could make your example work by simply renaming your `window.Person` variable created in the `click` callback. A more proper approach, however, would be to use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). This will keep the window scope cleaner and solve your issue.

Additionally, when it comes to naming variables and constructors, the following guidelines are usually used:

- Constructor function names should start with a capital (for instance `function Person`)
- Normal variables should start with a lower case (for instance `var person`)

This avoids any confusion when writing things like `var person = new Person()`.

The end result looks something like this:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.alert = function(){
        alert("hello " + this.name);
    };
}

function Area (location, name){
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.alert = function(){
        alert("hello " + this.name + " you live in " + this.location);
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var person;
    $(".button").click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).text();
        person = new Person(clicked);
        person.alert();  
    });

    $(".button2").click(function(){
        var location = $(this).text();
        var name =  person.name;
        var area = new Area(location, name);
        area.alert();  
    });
});
```

If you need to access the `area` variable outside of the `click` function you can of course also move `var area` directly under the declaration `var person`.

Comment: You're welcome! If you're looking at patterns to keep your window scope clean I also suggesting have a look at IFFE's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: Answer better than mine, upvoted. Also it does not pollute the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the instance in the outside scope:

```
var myPerson, myArea;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".button").click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).text();
        myPerson = new Person(clicked);
        myPerson.alert();  
    });

    $(".button2").click(function(){
        var location = $(this).text();
        var name =  myPerson.name;
        myArea = new Area(location, name);
        myArea.alert();  
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, it's better not to pollute the global scope, his solution is better.